# How to sort a observablecollection(of String)

Tags: vb.net, observablecollection

All I need is a simple way to sort the strings in the collection. I can't find anything online. Everybody is using lambda expressions which I don't think works for just a string collection?
Thanks,

```
   Public Property FilterCollection As New ObservableCollection(Of String)

  From d In FilterCollection Order By (Function(d) d)()
```

Comment: Why would a lambda not work for a collection of strings?

Comment: Idk..Idk how to call a lambda expression for just a string..I get compile errors if I use above expression

Answer (score -2):

My VB.Net is rusty but try

```
Dim sortedCollection = FilterCollection.OrderBy(Function(s) s)
```